# Static metrics with whole-cylinder symmetry

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, symmetry

Let's say that a spacetime has whole-cylinder symmetry if we can write the metric in "standard form" as $$ \mathrm ds^2=e^{2(K-U)}\left(\mathrm dr^2-\mathrm dt^2\right)+W^2e^{-2U}\mathrm d\varphi^2+e^{2U}\mathrm dz^2, \qquad(\ast)$$where $K$, $U$ and $W$ are functions of $t,r$ only.

This metric ansatz is essentially (locally) equivalent (modulo "global" considerations for example regarding the range and interpretation of $\varphi$) to the assumption that 1) the spacetime has two spacelike, pairwise commuting Killing vector fields that are pointwise linearly independent, 2) the group action generated by the Killing fields is orthogonally transitive, or equivalently, the metric is symmetric with respect to reflexions through any plane intersecting the $z$ axis orthogonally and any plane that contains the $z$ axis.

---

I want to further suppose that such a spacetime is also static. It would be incredibly convenient if this simply implied that the functions $K$, $U$ and $W$ depend on $r$ only. However I am unable to see that. Let $\xi_t$ be the timelike Killing vector, $\xi_\varphi$ and $\xi_z$ the spacelike Killing vectors (which are $\xi_\varphi=\partial_\varphi$ and $\xi_z=\partial_z$ in the standard coordinates).

If the metric has the form $(\ast)$ but with $K$, $U$ and $W$ are time-independent, then this would imply that

1. $\xi_t$ can be chosen orthogonal to both $\xi_\varphi$ and $\xi_z$;
2. the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g_3$ spanned by $\xi_t,\xi_\varphi$ and $\xi_z$ is Abelian.

I do not see that merely the assumption of both staticity and whole-cylinder symmetry implies that $\xi_t$ is orthogonal to $\xi_\varphi,\xi_z$ nor that the group is Abelian.

Also scouring some of the relevant literature gave me no definite answers. In some papers I have seen the claims that whole-cylinder symmetry + staticity implies all of the above, but with no proofs and no references given.

Therefore my questions are as follows:

- Does staticity together with whole-cylinder symmetry imply that the metric can be written in the form $(\ast)$ with time-independent metric functions? If yes, please provide a paper or book where this is proven.
- If not then what are the minimal set of physical or geometrical assumptions one needs to impose for this condition?

Comment: check the condition for a static metric in a GR book such as D'Inverno or Ryder.... I think you will see how to construct your argument from there.

Comment: @NelsonVanegasA. I flipped through d'Inverno and there is nothing there that would be useful to me. I know the conditions for static metric. What I want to see is that a static *and* cylindrically symmetric metric has the two symmetries "compatible" with each other, which is highly nontrivial.